# Is it possible to execute a SQL and determine which table the SQL actually affected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Is it possible to execute a SQL and determine which table the SQL actually affected?

Comment: Absolutely. Look at the SQL that is being executed. What more do you want?

Comment: Maybe looking at query execution plan you can have a more precise idea on what is going on, as it would point out the tables which composes the views and other non-obvious stuff.

Comment: Rich, the requirement goes like this...I get a huge list of Insert/Update/Delete queries (running into millions) every day. I need to parse through these queries and identify the tables that were inserted / updated / deleted. Since I get only this dump, I will not have access to the execution plan either...

Comment: You will need to clarify more

Comment: TheGameiswar, I have provided a more detailed note. hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: What format is the data you're receiving?  And do you have server access? ie. Can you run a trace? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: All the queries are stacked in a table in a nvarchar column. That's all I get. I do not have access to the Server nor can I run a trace. I'm trying to figure out of I can read each row and find the table that was affected.

Comment: Any chance table names also have database info in the naming?  ie. `database.dbo.tablename` or `dbo.tablename`

Comment: Aaron, You will find queries in all formats. a) table prefixed with db name b)prefixed with default schema dbo c)prefixed with user defined schema d)with no schema prefixed.

Comment: For *trivial* queries, you can just locate the table name in a fixed position relative to the starting keywords. E.g. `INSERT [INTO] <Table Name>`, `UPDATE <Table Name>`, `DELETE [FROM] <Table Name>`. Unfortunately, this becomes decidedly non-trivial if `DELETE` or `UPDATE` are using the MS extensions which use arbitrary `FROM` clauses *and* the above `<Table Name>`s are aliases from that `FROM` clause. At that point, you really need a full-blown SQL *parser*.

Comment: Thanks Damien. I have already started building the parser; just when i found the going getting tough, posted it here to see if there are system functions or a simpler way to get this done.

Comment: try http://www.sqlparser.com/

Comment: You should really add samples of your code, to see if it's possible to use any kind of (simple) parsing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How "n rows affected" works in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233856/how-n-rows-affected-works-in-sql-server)