# How "n rows affected" works in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @EndID BIGINT,
        @StartID BIGINT,
        @n_batchSize INT = 3000

SET @EndID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table WHERE NewColumn IS NULL)

WHILE (@EndID>0)
BEGIN
      SET @StartID = @EndID - @n_batchSize;

      UPDATE Table WITH (ROWLOCK)
      SET NewColumn = 
        (CASE
            WHEN (ColumnA IS NOT NULL AND ColumnA > 0) THEN ColumnA
            ELSE 
            (
                SELECT  TableC.ID
                FROM TableB AS B WITH(NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN TableC AS C WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    ON B.ID = C.ID
                WHERE  C.ID = Table.ID
            ) END
        )
      WHERE ID BETWEEN @StartID AND @EndID
      AND NewColumn IS NULL

      SET @EndID = @EndID - @n_batchSize;

      WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
END
```

The above script was executed to perform data patching operation.

After waited for it to be completed, there are some values of `NewColumn` remained null.

The count of `NewColumn IS NULL` is 140 and the same script executed for second time. Upon it's completion, few of the batches with "n rows affected" as shown below:

[image]

And when I check count of `NewColumn IS NULL`, it's still 140. So my best guess is the "n rows affected" is due to the select query from the `SET` part.

To perform experiment, I ran specifically targeting one record and see how it works with the below query

```
UPDATE Table WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET NewColumn = 
    (CASE
        WHEN (ColumnA IS NOT NULL AND ColumnA > 0) THEN ColumnA
        ELSE 
        (
            SELECT  TableC.ID
            FROM TableB AS B WITH(NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN TableC AS C WITH(NOLOCK) 
                ON terminal.LocationID = location.LocationID
            WHERE  C.ID = Table.ID
        ) END
    )
WHERE ID = 1 AND EntryZoneID IS NULL
```

The result is as below:

[image]

Based on the result, it seems like my guess was wrong. The statement is not because of the sub-select-query?

Comment: Is your `CASE`statement returning `null` perhaps? An `UPDATE` statement will still show the numbers of rows affected, even if it ultimately changes nothing (i.e. sets `null` columns to `null`)

Comment: It's also possible that your table has a `TRIGGER` against it, that could be giving you `n rows affected` messages too.

Comment: @DavidG: So it means the first `0 rows affected` was by `sets null columns to null` and the second `1 rows affected` was due to trigger? It means trigger will be triggered even when there is `0 rows affected`?

Comment: Well it could be the other way round too. Triggers can be set to run before or after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n rows affected would be coming from your update query. It shows how many rows were updated. It's not because of the subquery. It's because your update query is updating the rows based on your where condition

```
 WHERE ID BETWEEN @StartID AND @EndID
  AND NewColumn IS NULL
```

Comment: The count of `NewColumn IS NULL` remained 140 no matter how many times I executed the scripts and when I manually calculated `n rows affected`, it's far beyond 140. So I don't think it's because of the `Where` part as well

Comment: Yes you're right, the additional `n rows affected` was due to the table has some replication operation and hence the doubled up amount